# Not sure how to render results of useEffect in browser

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

Following is the data useEffect is returning in console log:

```
{
    "sql": {
        "external": false,
        "sql": [
            "SELECT\n      date_trunc('day', (\"line_items\".created_at::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) \"line_items__created_at_day\", count(\"line_items\".id) \"line_items__count\"\n    FROM\n      public.line_items AS \"line_items\"\n  GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 10000",
            []
        ],
        "timeDimensionAlias": "line_items__created_at_day",
        "timeDimensionField": "LineItems.createdAt",
        "order": {
            "LineItems.createdAt": "asc"
        }
```

I want to be able to render the above in my react app.

```
const ChartRenderer = ({ vizState }) => {

  let ur = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(vizState.query));
  let u = "http://localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/sql?query=" + ur;
  console.log(u)
  useEffect(() => {
      if(u !=="http://localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/sql?query=undefined") {
                        fetch(u)
          .then(response => (response.json()))
          .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)))
        }},[u]);
  const { query, chartType, pivotConfig } = vizState;
  const component = TypeToMemoChartComponent[chartType];
  const renderProps = useCubeQuery(query);
  return component && renderChart(component)({ ...renderProps, pivotConfig })
};
```

Comment: You are supposed to set state inside `useEffect`. And you are not supposed to pass a regular variable `u` to `useEffect`. You are supposed to pass a state that you want `useEffect` to monitor. A regular variable cannot be monitored for changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use a state variable to persist data and update it whenever the API returns some data. In a functional component, you can use the `useState` hook for this purpose.

```
const ChartRenderer = ({ vizState }) => {
    // useState takes in an initial state value, you can keep it {} or null as per your use-case.
    const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
    let ur = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(vizState.query));
    let u = "http://localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/sql?query=" + ur;
    console.log(u)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(u !=="http://localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/sql?query=undefined") {
            fetch(u)
                .then(response => (response.json()))
                .then(data => {
                    // You can modify the data here before setting it to state.
                    setResponse(data);
                })
    }},[u]);

    // Use 'response' here or pass it to renderChart

    const { query, chartType, pivotConfig } = vizState;
    const component = TypeToMemoChartComponent[chartType];
    const renderProps = useCubeQuery(query);

    return component && renderChart(component)({ ...renderProps, pivotConfig })
};
```

You can read more about `useState` in the official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: thanks for your response! this worked in the app! now i am having issues rendering 'response'..the app won't let me render it this way: '  return component && renderChart(component)({ ...renderProps, pivotConfig }) && <code>{JSON.stringify(response.sql, null, 2)}</code>; ' implementing it this way hides 'component' and 'renderChart' only 'response' displays. how else is it possible to display' response' in the app?

Comment: If you wish to display both the chart and response, include both of them inside a `div` tag. The way you are doing will always display the last true value or null, which is response in your expression case. The updated code may look like this: 
`<div>{renderChart(component)({ ...renderProps, pivotConfig })} <code>{JSON.stringify(response.sql, null, 2)}</code></div>`